# How to format a ruby version string using sed and regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex, sed

### Background

I would like to format the string returned by `ruby -v`.

### Code

```
pattern="" # what do I put in here?
ruby -v | cut -d " " -f2 | sed 's/$pattern/g'
```

### Output

`ruby -v` => `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]`

`ruby -v | cut -d " " -f2` => `2.3.3p222`

### Expected

What I want to be outputted by piping `ruby -v | cut -d " " -f2` to `sed`: `2.3.3`.

Comment: You could also also Ruby itself for its version number with `ruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep for this:

```
$ ruby -v | grep -Po '\d+(\.\d+){2}'
2.5.1
```

Or just use ruby itself:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are looking to have `2.33` in your final result. If yes, this is what you can do.

```
$ ruby -v | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk -F'p' '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: What does `awk -F` specify?

Comment: `awk -F` acts as a delimiter separator, in this case it was `p`

Comment: Why call `awk` twice when you can do it in one go: `awk '{ split($2, vsn, "p"); print vsn[1] }'`. If you want patch version then it is stored in `vsn[2]`.